# R: Not meaningful for factors even though its data type is numeric

Tags: r

I'm trying to filter by a column which has a "numeric" type already, but it keeps telling me its not meaningful to compare it using ">".

[image]

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: try `myfact <- factor(letters[1:10])` and then `mode(myfact)` : a factor has a numeric mode.

Comment: Use `str(mydata)` instead of `sapply(mydata, mode)`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

We can convert those `factor` columns to `numeric`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
mydata %<>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- sapply(mydata, is.factor)
mydata[i1] <- lapply(mydata[i1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

and then the code should work

Comment: I'm confused as to why this was necessary if it already says that column's data type is numeric

Comment: @D.Liang  Your image is not clear for others to understand the problem.  Please use dput to show a small reproducible example